# Create new strings

Tags: string, sed

I have a text files with lines like this:

```
boat
house
car
```

I would like to create a new file which looks like this:

```
boat.mydomain.com
house.mydomain.com
car.mydomain.com
```

How can I do this using sed?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/.*/&.mydomain.com/' input_file >output_file
```

As Felix Kling pointed out, this works, too:

```
sed 's/$/.mydomain.com/' input_file >output_file
```

Comment: Yes, that works, too. Saves typing two characters, as well. ;-)

Comment: Ah I deleted my comment, not necessary anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file
boat
house
car

$ sed -r 's/(.*)/\1.mydomain.com/' file
boat.mydomain.com
house.mydomain.com
car.mydomain.com
```